# HighChart Drilldown axis automatically show the differences instead of actual label

Tags: javascript, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/sohxow92/

The `y-axis` after clicking on `drilldown` automatically show the short label, `try 1-2h`, and take a look at `y-axis` you will see, starting from `68`, it shows `8, 12` and so on.
What config of `highchart` do I need to modify to make this show the original label?
Following is part of the drilldown object.

```
"drilldown": {
    "xAxis": {
    "type": "category",
    "labels": {
      "overflow": "justify"
    }
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "labels": {
      "overflow": "justify"
    },
    "title": {
      "text": "Visits"
    }
  },
  "activeDataLabelStyle": {
    "textDecoration": "none"
  },
  "activeAxisLabelStyle": {
    "textDecoration": "none"
  },
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what is the desired result. You can modify the y axis labels  in drilldown/drillup events - see https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drillup. On these events you can update axis and its labels.